# Creating new PsObject

Tags: powershell

I must be doing something wrong here results are empty, I tried converting html with `PsObject` it requires `-Append` that creates multiple html tables and not suited to send an email, any help appreciated.

```
Foreach($sender in $senders){

    $users=Get-TransportServer|Get-MessageTrackingLog  -Start (Get-Date).AddHours(-4) -ResultSize Unlimited -Sender $sender.PrimarySmtpAddress |?{$_.Recipients -notlike "*@domain.us" -and $_.RecipientCount -eq "1" -and $_.RecipientStatus -notlike "*,*" -and $_.eventid -eq 'RECEIVE' } 
    }
    $users | % {
    $t = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Sender = $_.Sender
        Receiver = $_.Recipients
        Messagesubject=$_.Messagesubject
        RecipientCount =$_.RecipientCount 
        TimeStamp=$_.TimeStamp
      }
      $outtbl += $t
    }
    $outtbl
```

Comment: Where are those `Get-` functions defined?  Your question isn't clear.

Comment: Can't say for sure why it's not working, but if you're only after the Receive events you'd be a lot better off using the -EventID parameter of Get-MessageTrackinglog to filter out everything but the Receive events up front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was it

```
foreach ( $sender in $senders ) {
  Get-TransportServer |
    Get-MessageTrackingLog -Start (Get-Date).AddHours(-4) -ResultSize Unlimited -Sender $sender.PrimarySmtpAddress |
      Where-Object { ($_.Recipients -notlike "*@domain.us") -and
      ($_.RecipientCount -eq 1) -and
      ($_.RecipientStatus -notlike "*,*") -and
      ($_.eventid -eq 'RECEIVE') } | ForEach-Object {
        $results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Sender = $_.Sender
        Receiver = $_.Recipients
        MessageSubject = $_.MessageSubject
        RecipientCount = $_.RecipientCount
        TimeStamp = $_.TimeStamp
      }
    }


    }
$results| ConvertTo-Html -Head $style| Out-File $reportpath
```

Comment: You don't need a `$results` variable. You can enclose your `foreach` loop in a scriptblock, execute it with `&`, and pipe it to `ConvertTo-Html`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need `$users`, `$outtbl`, or `$t`?

```
foreach ( $sender in $senders ) {
  Get-TransportServer |
    Get-MessageTrackingLog -Start (Get-Date).AddHours(-4) -ResultSize Unlimited -Sender $sender.PrimarySmtpAddress |
      Where-Object { ($_.Recipients -notlike "*@domain.us") -and
      ($_.RecipientCount -eq 1) -and
      ($_.RecipientStatus -notlike "*,*") -and
      ($_.eventid -eq 'RECEIVE') } | ForEach-Object {
      [PSCustomObject] @{
        Sender = $_.Sender
        Receipients = $_.Recipients
        MessageSubject = $_.MessageSubject
        RecipientCount = $_.RecipientCount
        TimeStamp = $_.TimeStamp
      }
    }
}
```

(Not tested - this is just an example of how to eliminate unnecessary variables and write clearer code.)

This code sample requires PowerShell 3.0 or newer because it uses `[PSCustomObject]`.

Comment: I'm wondering why it needs the PSCustomObject at all.  All it needed was a Select and that list of properties.

Comment: Hey bill this is what stopped me from using [pscustomobject] its ps2 not its working surprisingly

Comment: Becuase i need html and when I select and out-file it requires append and creates multiple header

Comment: @mjolinor - true; I wasn't sure if he needed properties from the object returned from `Get-TransportServer` (built PSObject just in case).

Comment: @StackOverFlowsucks - IMO you should invest some more time in learning how the PowerShell pipeline works.

Comment: @Bill sure

now the out-file HTML is `
IsReadOnly IsFixedSize IsSynchronized Keys Values SyncRoot Count
False False False System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection System.Object 5
False False False System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection System.Object 5 `

Comment: I would start with the PowerShell basics and learn how objects and pipelines work in PowerShell. Things will be less frustrating and less confusing in the long run.

Comment: LOL, you are deleting my comments >, here again, can you tell me the logic behind why should I learn PowerShell basic just to make a report?

Comment: Sorry, it's not me who is deleting anything. PowerShell basics are a prerequisite for doing things effectively in PowerShell. You can't learn algebra before learning arithmetic.

Comment: I know more than basic My job absolutely do not require PowerShell, just once in a blue moon.